# Visual Studio 2017 not showing System.Text.RegularExpressions comments/docs for .NET Core projects only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

For example System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex. No comments/docs are shown for it.

Also non-Core projects don't suffer from this issue.

I have already tried re-installing .NET Core SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ran

```
Install-Package System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

in the packet manager and now it's working